# Oracle: access to column with name "all"

Tags: oracle

everybody. I have table, where one of the column names is "All" and I want to get this column. I trying to use next simple query:

```
SELECT All
FROM TableName
```

, but I have ORA-00936. When I use just:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
```

I see required column with "All" name. In table specification I see next SQL script:

```
create table TableName
(
  houseid   NUMBER not null,
  id        NUMBER not null,
  note      VARCHAR2(255),
  all       NUMBER
)
```

How I can get access to "All" column?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT "ALL" from TABLENAME
```

this is a good reason not to use oracle reserved keywords as table or column names but by using the  doublequote `" "` you can access them.

Keep in mind that when you  use `" "` you must be consistent in your case in the statement.  Not  `"All"` and `"all"` in the same statement

Comment: Thank you so much. I absolutely agree with you, but DB is not my

Answer (score 0):

Put it in quotes.

```
SELECT "all"
FROM TableName
```

Comment: The other answer is correct in that the string inside double quotes is case sensitive and the column name would be uppercase.

Comment: Really? Look at the CREATE TABLE statement in the question.  The column name is lower case.

Comment: @MarkLeiber Look again. The CREATE TABLE statement doesn't contain double quotes around the column name - this creates the column case-insensitive (essentially converting it to uppercase), which makes `ALL` the correct name.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the client tool being used, but surely that `create table` script as it stands should fall over with an `invalid identifier` error? I would want to `describe` the table first to get the correct case before agreeing with either of these answers.